# Break from raw_input in while loop

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I've written a very simple dice rolling script in Python. It'll allow you to roll three times. However, I don't know how to break out of the while loop and avoid the raw_input the final time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from random import randrange, uniform

def rollDice():
  dice = randrange(3,18)
  print ("You rolled: %s" % dice)

maxReRoll = 2
c = 0
reRoll = "y"

while reRoll in ["Yes", "yes", "y", "Y"]:
  if c > maxReRoll:
    break
  else:
    rollDice()
    c+=1
    reRoll = raw_input("Roll again?  y/n ")
```

Comment: You say you want people to roll 3 times, but you have `maxReRoll = 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little swap is needed.

```
while reRoll in ["Yes", "yes", "y", "Y"]:
  rollDice()
  c+=1
  if c >= maxReRoll:  # notice the '>=' operator here
    break
  else:
    reRoll = raw_input("Roll again?  y/n ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
from random import randrange


def roll_dice():
    dice = randrange(3,18)
    print("You rolled: %s" % dice)

max_rolls = 2
c = 0
re_roll = "y"

while re_roll.lower() in ["yes", "y"] and (c < max_rolls):
    roll_dice()
    c += 1
    if c != max_rolls:
        re_roll = input("Roll again?  y/n ")
```